# React-Select - setData

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I get an object (technologies) from the database, what would be the correct way to set this object as a value in react-select?

I'm doing it as follows:

```
  const handleEditDev = useCallback(async (id: number) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await api.get(`/developers/?id=${id}`);
      const { developer } = data;

      formRef.current?.setData({
        technologies: developer.technologies,
      });

      console.log(developer.technologies);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);
```

But i receive the error:

[image]

I understand that I should go through this object to extract the keys, but how would I do that?

Return of console.log(developer.technologies);

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(item, i) => {
    return (
        <option key={`developer-list-${item.id}-${i}`} value={item}>{item}</option>
    )
}
```

Comment: It is not recommended to use indexes as keys. Rather use a unique, stable attribute of the object such as an id `key={item.id}`. Decent explanation in the docs [Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys)

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps